no se visualizan los cambios en mi terminal ni en la pagina web la estoy realizando con react se supone que cree un nuevo campo para un formulario
se crea un formulario para ambiental sin embargo inicie ealizando la estructura de dicho formulario pero cuando ejecuto npm run start  no me toma los cambios que realice en mi codigo ni se me visualizan los cambios en la terminal de mi proyecto  foto inicial el campo de mi pagina foto siguiente mi visual  con el codigo y la terminal sin generarme cambios apesar de realizar modificaciones al codigo  

Tu método debería tener un return dentro... si no devuelve nada, no se "pinta" nada. Si lo tienes... cómo pretendes que debuguemos un problema a partir de una IMAGEN?¿?????!! El código es texto... proporciona un [mre] o al menos absolutamente todos los detalles... no somos adivinos. Somos programadores.
